# Relacionar dos tablas en eloquent con diferente tipo de dato

Tags: laravel, base-de-datos, eloquent

Tengo dos tablas en diferentes bases de datos que relaciono por medio de eloquent, pero tengo problemas al acceder a algunos registros, ya que por alguna razon al obtener los datos se convierte la columna en int, vale la pena resaltar que en la base de datos el tipo de dato es string

Mi modelo encabezado desde el cual obtengo los datos de la tabla con problemas

```
...

/**
*
* @var array
*/
protected $casts = [
   'CodCliente'   =>  'string',
];

...

public function cliente(){
    return $this->hasOne(ClienteMax::class, 'CODIGO_CLIENTE', 'CodCliente');
}
```

Mi modelo cliente

```
/**
 * The database connection used by the model.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $connection = 'CONEXION2';

/**
 * The database table used by the model.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $table = 'tabla';


/**
 * The database primary key
 *
 * @var string
 */
public $primaryKey = 'CODIGO_CLIENTE';




protected $casts = [
    'CODIGO_CLIENTE' => 'string',
];
```

Ya intente de todo pero nada funciona, ¿alguna idea de que puede estar pasando?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: asumo que CodCliente es el valor a recuperar, ¿es la llave primaria?

Comment: La llave primaria en este caso seria `CODIGO_CLIENTE`

Comment: Si, pero este es el valor que deseas recuperar y se te convierte a string?

Comment: en BD `CODIGO_CLIENTE` es un valor string, pero al recuperarlo se convierte a int y quiero evitarlo ya que los valores que esa columna son números que empiezan con 0, ejem : 001324, 096745, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basándonos en lo que compartes en tus comentarios, te expongo lo siguiente:

- Eloquent asume que cada entidad tiene una llave primaria de tipo entero y auto incremental, por lo cual será *casteada* a ese tipo de dato **`int`**
- Si ese no es el caso debemos entonces anular tanto la naturaleza definida de auto increment como de tipo de dato para que se ajuste a las características que tienes definidas en dicha entidad.

Entonces en tu modelo, debes definir lo siguiente:

```
public $incrementing = false;
protected $keyType = 'string';
```

Prueba con lo anterior y elimina esta configuración:

```
protected $casts = [
    'CODIGO_CLIENTE' => 'string',
];
```

**Referencia**

- [Convenciones de modelos en Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#eloquent-model-conventions)

Comment: Hola @BetaM complementando la solución que me das, tenia otro problema con la tabla de la cual recuperaba los datos, era que me faltaba eliminar unos espacios en blanco que tenia el campo, muchas gracias por tu respuesta